# Does it matter what order I place my workers when brewing?

Tags: fiz

Some works have abilities like 25% chance of 25% faster brew time.  Does it matter if I place this worker first in the task order (i.e. cleaning), or last (bottling)?  Will it reduce the overall brew time or is it just for their task that they have a chance in reducing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the craft bonuses are applied regardless of where you place them in the production line. The important statistic that you should base your consideration on are as follows;

This means that you should assign your workers to the roles they're best suited to based on the statistics bonuses for each role below;

- Cleaning - Patience
- Cooking - Intelligence and Dexterity
- Fermenting - Intelligence and Patience
- Packaging - Dexterity

Choosing a worker with statistics that match the role requirements will improve the quality of your brew in addition to the craft bonuses.

Comment: just to clarify, so if my packager has the increase brew speed by 25%, then it'll affect the entire brewing time, not just the bottling part?

Comment: "brew" in this game refers to the entire process

Comment: I know, but usually you don't see them apply their 'bonus' until its their turn to do something

Comment: Still testing... the speed bonus seems to drop off once that worker becomes inactive, although putting a worker in the role of cooking instead of cleaning does seem to reduce the duration of the brew slightly (I think this is because cooking is a slightly longer process than cleaning or packing though since cleaning comes before cooking during a brew)

Comment: I think you were right the first time, I put a double brewing speed guy at the packaging and the entire process went super fast.